# Create a script that write a local image file to override hard drive on a remote server using dd and netcat

Tags: bash, ssh, netcat, dd

I am struggling for a while trying to create a script that write a local image file to override hard drive on a remote server. 
for that i am trying to use Linux dd over netcat with gzip compression.
will ssh a remote server, execute a remote dd over netcat command for listening on a specific port, and then launch a command to write an image for this remote server. 
Im not sure why it is not working for me, I have many assumptions and I tried to do it on many ways, including running remote scripts on the background, or having the ssh session itself on the background - but it does not work for me from within a script.
the commands i am trying to run:

1. ssh remote server:

   ```
   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i id_rsa (SERVER_IP)
   ```
2. on the remote server start lisen session of dd over nc on port 9023 and decompress using gunzip:

   ```
   /bin/nc -l -p 9023|/bin/gunzip -c|/bin/dd bs=64k of=/dev/sda &
   ```
3. exit to the main server and execute:

   ```
   dd if=/var/tmp/ADT/Server-full/image.gz bs=64k |pv|nc (SERVER_IP) 9023
   ```

When trying to run the commands one by one it works and the dd sessions is working. when trying to run it from a script the dd session hangs immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect local input through a compressed `ssh` session, and use that input on the other side. You can do this directly without netcat:

```
ssh -C user@server 'dd of=/dev/sda' < /path/to/local.image
```

Add the other necessary options you need for `ssh` and `dd`.

The `CompressionLevel` option in `man ssh` should be interesting too for your use case.

Comment: It works like a charm! thanks.
Now i am trying to monitor this process, when it was using dd and nc for both listen and write i could monitor it with pv. with this solution it does not work. any idea how to monitor the progress?

Comment: You can add `pv` in the pipeline right in front of `dd`, like `ssh host 'pv | dd ...' < /path/to/local.image`